# OpenCV CUDA Function Missing - namespace "cv:cuda" has no member "resize"

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-c++

I'm trying to use OpenCV 4.1 with CUDA 10 to resize lots of large tif stacks, but VS2017 doesn't see the function `resize` in the library.  It's happy with a subset of the `cv::cuda` library, but doesn't see all the functions as listed here: https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.0/d1/d1a/namespacecv_1_1cuda.html

I'm including `#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>`, and Intellisense shows me the autocompletes of `cuda::` of `PtrSz, registerPageLocked, resetDevice, setBufferPoolConfig`, but no resize...?

I adapted the old OpenCV 3(?ish; here https://www.opencv-srf.com/p/introduction.html) tutorial online to setup my VS project:

1. Created a system level environment variable $(OPENCV_DIR) pointing to the OpenCV build folder
2. In the Project properties I added:

   - **All Configurations:**
   - C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories `$(OPENCV_DIR)\include`
   - Linker -> General -> Additional LibraryDirectories `$(OPENCV_DIR)\x64\vc15\lib` *here, and below, I've changed the vc## folder to reflect that I'm using VS2017*
   - Debugging -> Environment `PATH=$(OPENCV_DIR)\x64\vc15\bin;%PATH%`
   - **In Configuration Manager...**
   - Set Active solution platform: to x64
   - **Debug:**
   - Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies `opencv_world410d.lib`
   - **Release:**
   - Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies `opencv_world410.lib`

If I try to compile using `cv::cuda::resize(...)` I get the compile error of `namespace "cv::cuda" has not member "resize"`.  If instead I try to use one of the functions it sees in that namespace, e.g. `std::cout << "CUDA device count: " << cuda::getCudaEnabledDeviceCount();` it outputs `CUDA device count: 0` and trying something like `std::cout << "CUDA device: " << cuda::getDevice();` gives the following error:
`OpenCV(4.1.0) Error: No CUDA support (The library is compiled without CUDA support) in throw_no_cuda, file c:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\core\include\opencv2\core\private.cuda.hpp, line 107`

I'm confused, firstly, why it only sees a subset of the functions available in that cv::cuda namespace, and secondly, why I don't have CUDA support?
Do I need to compile OpenCV on my machine first?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are including the proper header files. In your case **cudawarping.hpp** should be the right one. Most likely you like to do some matrix arithmetic as well so you need to include **cudaarithm.hpp** .

```
#include <opencv2/cudaarithm.hpp>
#include "opencv2/cudawarping.hpp"
```

Here is the api documentation to resize: [Documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.3.0/db/d29/group__cudawarping.html#ga4f5fa0770d1c9efbadb9be1b92a6452a)

Hope it helps...